# Looking help in unix commands to extract and replace string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am looking for help with Unix shell scripting. I have an URL like below:

```
https://jenkinsurl.com/job/GitHub%20Organization%20Scans/job/Project_Dev/job/reponame/job/dev/72/
```

I want to convert above string to  below format:

```
"/var/jenkins_home/jobs/GitHub Organization Scans/jobs/Project_Dev/jobs/reponame/branches/dev/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/log"
```

I used the below script to extract a part of it:

```sh
formatted_url=$(echo "$build_url_val" | cut -d'/' -f5-)
```

**The output :**

```
GitHub%20Organization%20Scans/job/Securtization_Dev/job/awsFileRetrievalAPI/job/dev/72/
```

But in the above string I want to replace `GitHub%20Organization%20Scans` to GitHub Organization Scans, I guess(`%20` represent space in encoded format) and also replace `job` with `jobs`.

I am looking for help to get output as:

```
"/var/jenkins_home/jobs/GitHub Organization Scans/jobs/Project_Dev/jobs/reponame/branches/dev/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/log"
```

Comment: You seem to work with another URL in your output example than what you show first.

Comment: you can easily construct a `sed` script that would convert all `%nn` to their appropriate ASCII value. `newStr=$(echo "$oldStr"|sed 's/%20/ /g; .....')` . Good luck.

Comment: Agree with Shellter. And your question isn't much clear comparing input and output. From what I understand is you would like to replace %20 to space and job to jobs. Below is the code for the same

url="https://jenkinsurl.com/job/GitHub%20Organization%20Scans/job/Project_Dev/job/reponame/job/dev/72/"

echo $url|sed 's/%20/ /g;s/job/jobs/g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Have hardcoded using sed command to append the text at the front and the end.

```
formatted_url="https://jenkinsurl.com/job/GitHub%20Organization%20Scans/job/Project_Dev/job/reponame/job/dev/72/"

echo $formatted_url | cut -d'/' -f4- | sed 's/%20/ /g;s/job/jobs/g' | sed 's/^/\/var\/jenkins_home\//;s/$/branches\/dev\/builds\/$BUILD_NUMBER\/log/'
```

**Command wise explanation:**

1)echo $formatted_url  ==> Print the value of formatted_url variable

2)cut -d'/' -f4-  ==> will cut the url from 4th word with slash as delimiter

3)sed 's/%20/ /g;s/job/jobs/g' ==> Replaces %20 with space and job with jobs

4)sed 's/^//var/jenkins_home//;s/$/branches/dev/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/log/'  ==> Appends the path "/var/jenkins_home/" at the start of the output and appends the path "branches/dev/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/log" at the end of the output.

BUILD_NUMBER should be replaced with your value

**Output:**

/var/jenkins_home/jobs/GitHub Organization Scans/jobs/Project_Dev/jobs/reponame/jobs/dev/72/branches/dev/builds/<BUILD_NUMBER>/log